# Get the client_id of the IAM proxy on GCP Cloud composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to trigger Airflow DAG inside of a composer environment with cloud functions. In order to do that I need to get the client id as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#python). I've tried with curl command but it doesn't return any value. With a python script I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_client_id.py", line 55, in <module>
    get_client_id(
  File "get_client_id.py", line 40, in get_client_id
    print(query_string['client_id'][0])
KeyError: 'client_id'
```

Python code:

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests
import six.moves.urllib.parse

# Authenticate with Google Cloud.
# See: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
authed_session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(
    credentials)

project_id = 'my-project'
location = 'my-region'
composer_environment = 'my-env'

environment_url = (
    'https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{}/locations/{}'
    '/environments/{}').format(project_id, location, composer_environment)
composer_response = authed_session.request('GET', environment_url)
environment_data = composer_response.json()
airflow_uri = environment_data['config']['airflowUri']



# The Composer environment response does not include the IAP client ID.
# Make a second, unauthenticated HTTP request to the web server to get the
# redirect URI.
redirect_response = requests.get(airflow_uri, allow_redirects=False)
redirect_location = redirect_response.headers['location']

# Extract the client_id query parameter from the redirect.
parsed = six.moves.urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_location)
query_string = six.moves.urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
print(query_string['client_id'][0])
```

cURL command:

```
curl -v my_airflow_url 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -o "client_id\=[A-Za-z0-9-]*\.apps\.googleusercontent\.com"
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get the Get the `client_id` of the IAM proxy?

Comment: Could you clarify if you are asking for `IAM` or `IAP`? Your title is poining to IAM but in code you have `...the IAP client ID`. If you are asking for `IAP`, did you see thread [How to authenticate programmatically to a Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (Cloud IAP)-secured resource using user default credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071544/)? Also there is a docs in GCP [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @PjoterS I'm asking for IAM. The code was provided by google in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#python

Comment: Hi @Dudes, are you using Composer v2? This code was written for Composer v1 and I think just needs an update to work for Composer v2, which is still in preview. I work on these tutorials and will raise a bug to address this.

Comment: Is indeed Composer v2.

Comment: @Dudes did you try to rewrite this to V2 or have you used Composer V1 to run this code?

Comment: I've tried with V1 and it works @PjoterS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better `visibility`.

As mentioned in the comment section by `@LEC` this configuration is compatible with `Cloud Composer V1` which can be found in GCP Documentation [Triggering DAGs with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#python).

At the moment there can be found two tabs `Cloud Composer 1 Guides` and `Cloud Composer 2 Guides`.
Under `Cloud Composer 1` is code used by the OP, but if you will check `Cloud Composer 2` under `Manage DAGs` > [Triggering DAGs with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf) you will get information that there is not proper documentation yet.

> This documentation page for Cloud Composer 2 is not yet available. Please use the [page for Cloud Composer 1](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf).

As solution, please use `Cloud Composer V1`.

Comment: The guide how to trigger a DAG using Stable API in Composer 2 was recently published: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-api

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide with instructions describing how to trigger a DAG in Composer 2/Airflow - https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-api